# What is the DeepLab Mobilenet v2 output and how to draw segmentation masks on Android?

Tags: java, android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, deeplab

I am pretty new to machine learning & Tensorflow. I used transfer learning to train a DeepLab mobilenet v2 model and would like to implement it in Android as tflite. I see that the output array is [1, 320, 320, 3]. I am wondering what the outputs of this array are? How do I draw the output segmentation mask on Android Java using Canvas?